# Convert random bezier Curves to 45°/90° angeled curves

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration, bezier-curve

Is it possible to automatically create a curve that looks exactly the same while converting its anchor points and bezier curves in a way so that the curve handle are all in 90°/45° positions afterwards? [image]

In this example i rotated a curve and by hand set new anchor point and curves handles.
1.) Is there a tool for that ? 
2.) If there is no tool, is there a mathematical basis to do this? 
Thx Guys !

Comment: If the curve started off by having all 45 degree anchors then sortof yes.

Comment: Also you may want to define if looks exactly same is mathematically same or just close enough to look same.

Comment: ideally mathematically the same of course, but i'd settle for indistinguishable with the naked eye.